# How do I create an "interactive" graphics device based on off-screen (bitmap) graphics in R?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, bitmap

Plotting large plots in R can be painfully slow. I'm trying some [workarounds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/statistical-methods-to-more-efficiently-plot-data-when-millions-of-points-are-pr) but even with the maximally-buffered "dbcairo" X11 device, plotting seems to take much longer than it could. I noticed that the "png" device is faster for both small plots and large plots.

Small plots, png() beats X11() by about 3x:

```
> system.time({X11(type="dbcairo"); plot(1:1e3); dev.off()})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.234   0.029   0.373 
> system.time({png("file.png",type="cairo"); plot(1:1e3); dev.off()})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.114   0.000   0.113 
> system.time({png("file.png",type="Xlib"); plot(1:1e3); dev.off()})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.056   0.000   0.107
```

Large plots, png() beats X11() by 2.3x to 46x:

```
> system.time({X11(type="dbcairo"); plot(1:1e5); dev.off()})
   user  system elapsed 
 14.420   0.157  15.491 
> system.time({png("file.png",type="cairo"); plot(1:1e5); dev.off()})
   user  system elapsed 
  6.790   0.001   6.826 
> system.time({png("file.png",type="Xlib"); plot(1:1e5); dev.off()})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.144   0.010   0.340
```

The results were pretty much the same with other X11() device types (being similar to "dbcairo") and other bitmap image types (being similar to "png"). I'm guessing png() type "cairo" takes longer than "Xlib" because it produces antialiased output.

With a medium-sized ggplot2 plot, I found that png() is 1.7x to 2.6x faster than X11() (that's using `png(..); plot(g); dev.off()`, not `ggsave()`)

Since I can load and reload a PNG file almost instantaneously using a minimalist image-viewer like "feh", I'm wondering why I don't use png() as my primary plotting device with R.

The problem of course is that the PNG file isn't written to disk until I call dev.off(). This crimps the style of the standard plotting interface, where I set the device once and then bring up various plots, sometimes adding lines or text, while viewing each change immediately in the plot window.

Would it be difficult to create a new R graphics device which writes image files to PNG (or some other image format), but uses a simple image viewer like "feh" to display them after each plotting command? In other words, I'm looking for an "interactive" plotting device like X11, but which uses the bitmap off-screen rendering facilities of existing devices such as png(), jpeg(), or tiff() to draw the image. Or maybe the png() device can be modified to have an option which gives it this behavior. (Or maybe I should be using knitR for everything ... but I am more familiar with the command line ...)

Comment: It's been 7 months since you asked this question. I am also interested on this. Did you find a way of implementing an interactive graphics device?

Comment: @rmagno No but there is a recent thread on the R-devel list you may be interested in lending your thoughts to, I don't think many people on that list use X11.

Comment: Mind giving the pointer? (I'm not able to find it.)

Comment: If you're not subscribed then it's probably not worth the trouble. [Here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2019-April/thread.html) is the archive.

Answer (score 1):

If X11 drives you up the wall and you don't want to use the RStudio plot viewer (or can't because you're on a remote server where you can't install RStudio Server), one interesting alternative is to use the [`rmote`](https://github.com/cloudyr/rmote) package. You can install it on either your own local R installation or, if you're SSHing into a remote machine and are willing to forward the port, on a remote R instance. Then any plots and help files you print will be redirected to a local web server, where you can access them from your browser.

It also comes with some nice extras, like:

- A plot history,
- The ability to right-click and save plots, as you would any other image in a browser, and
- The ability to choose which kinds of output are sent to the server.

I've found this a nice alternative to X11 forwarding with plots on a remote server, and it works well locally too